# Deleting duplicates but keeping first instance VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I am looking to delete duplicates (keeping blanks) in my data set which will contain 40-50,000 row.
The current code I have will keep the first and last instance but I just need to keep the first while deleting the rest.

```
Sub dltedups()

Dim toDelete As Range: Set toDelete = Sheet1.Rows(999999) '(to not start with 
a null range)
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim a As Range

For Each a In Sheet1.Range("A7", Sheet1.Range("A999999").End(xlUp))

If Not dict.Exists(a.Value2) Then
  dict(a.Value2) = 0 
Else

  If dict(a.Value2) = 1 Then Set toDelete = Union(toDelete, 
Sheet1.Rows(dict(a.Value2)))
  dict(a.Value2) = a.Row 

End If

Next
toDelete.Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Then just use RemoveDuplicates, it will remove all but the first one.

```
With Sheet1.Range("A7", Sheet1.Range("A999999").End(xlUp))
    .Value = .Value
    .RemoveDuplicates 1,xlno
End with
```

Comment: I am getting a runtime error 438.. Also will this be efficient with a large data set of 50,000+?

Comment: Everything works great, although It deletes the blanks as well. is there a way to eliminate that?

Comment: Nope, that was not specified in your question.  You are back to iteration and a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim C As Range
Dim objDic
Dim strMsg As String

Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set rng1 = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
For Each C In rng1
    If Len(C.Value) > 0 Then
        If Not objDic.Exists(C.Value) Then
            objDic.Add C.Value, 1
        Else
            C.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
```